# Asymptotics question

Tags: asymptotics, factorial, big-o-notation

Is $\frac {n!} {2!\cdot 4!\cdot 8!\dots (n/2)!}=O(4^n)$?

I am really stuck and I tend to believe it's true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried in proving it? Have you tried using definition of big O or limits?

Comment: the denominator is not clear. is it $2!*4!*6!...$? is it $2!*4!*8!*16!...$?

Comment: Tnx, I edited my question

Comment: So it appears there will be $n-2$ terms on the denominator. Can you pair up each of these terms with a term in the numerator that is greater than or equal to it? For instance, the last $n/2$ terms in $(n/2)!$ would pairs up with the last $n/2$ terms in $n!$ in the numerator and cancel out. Try this with the whole denominator.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? And do you prove or disprove it?

Comment: @ryan I think there are only $\log n$ factors in the denominator.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $\log n$ factors but $n-2$ _terms_, although I guess it depends on how you define them. I guess maybe $n-2$ factors would be more appropriate? I'm saying $$2! \cdot 4!  \cdot 8! \cdot \ldots \cdot (n/2)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \ldots$$ would have $2 + 4 + 8 + \ldots + n/2 = n-2$ factors. You can pair each of these up with one of the factors (specifically a larger or equal factor) in $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/4)!\cdots 2!} =
\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!} \frac{(n/2)!}{(n/4)!(n/4)!} \cdots \frac{4!}{2!2!} \frac{2!}{1!1!} = \\
\binom{n}{n/2} \binom{n/2}{n/4} \cdots \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{1} \leq 2^n 2^{n/2} \cdots 2^4 2^2 = 2^{n+n/2+\cdots+2+1} <2^{2n} = 4^n.
$$
Using Stirling's approximation we can get more refined asymptotics, but we leave this to the interested reader.

Comment: How to prove ${n\over 2}+{n\over 4}+...+2+1\lt n$?  And what if $n$ is not a power of $2$?

Comment: Then how is $n+{n\over 2}+{n\over 4}+...+2+1\lt n + n=2n$?

Comment: My previous comment was mistaken. We have $n + n/2 + n/4 + \cdots + 1 = n(1 + 1/2+1/4 + \cdots + 1/n) \leq n\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-i} = 2n$.

Comment: The OP implicitly assumes that $n$ is a power of 2.